# Angular2 @ViewChild is not picking up BaseChartDirective from ng2-charts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ng2-charts

I'm using ng2-charts v1.5.0, and I'm trying to get the chart to update with new data after a click. I'm following examples posted by others.

In my view I have:

```
<div style="display: block">

  <canvas #chart baseChart
              [data]="dChartData"
              [labels]="dChartLabels"
              [chartType]="dChartType"
              (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)">
  </canvas>

</div>
```

If I write:

```
@ViewChild( BaseChartDirective ) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

Then I get:

```
__zone_symbol__error : Error: Can't construct a query for the property "chart" of "ChartTest1WidgetComponent" since the query selector wasn't defined.
```

If I write:

```
@ViewChild( 'chart' ) chart: BaseChartDirective;
```

Then I call `this.chart.ngOnChanges({});`, but I get: `_this.chart.ngOnChanges is not a function`

This doesn't make sense to me. How can I get the proper view child that is a reference to `BaseChartDirective`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: 
`@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) private Chart: BaseChartDirective;`
and then `this.Chart.ngOnChanges({} as SimpleChanges)`.

But, the easier way to do it is to actually update the variable dChartData with the new data and it automatically should update your chart with the new data. It is quicker than using ngOnChanges. Hope this helps!

Comment: What version of ng2-charts are you using?

Comment: ng2-charts Version  1.5.0, chart.js 2.4.0

Comment: BaseChartDirective is undefined for me. How are you importing it?

Comment: import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';  Did you import and include ChartsModule in your module.ts?                                            (import { ChartsModule } from 'ng2-charts/ng2-charts')

Comment: That was my problem BaseChartDirective wasn't imported correctly.